# simple url with ui-router in angular.js

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I made a simple one page app with angular.js.
And ui-router was used.

The output url:

```
example.com/index.html#/profile
```

But I want like this:

```
example.com/profile
```

How can I solve this problem?

---

simple router code added

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('profile', {
        url: "/profile",
        templateUrl: "views/profile.html",
        controller: "ProfileCtrl",
        resolve: {
            deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                    name: 'app',
                    insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before', // load the above css files before '#ng_load_plugins_before'
                    files: [
                        'controllers/profile.js'
                    ]
                });
            }]
        }
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Set Html5 mode true in your app.js

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

Comment: If I set the html5mode, how can I set server side route?